# Redirection of tab is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, jquery-tabs

In my about us page I have 6 tabs (company, the founders, team, accolades, careers, philosophy ). In About us menu there are also 6 dropdown as same as tabs. When I click on the dropdown links I need to open the respective tabs How can i solve this??? I have tried 
`about_us_trial.php#company` but its not working.

here is my tab script

```
$("a[href='#company'], a[href='#founders'], a[href='#team'], a[href='#accolades'], a[href='#careers'], a[href='#philosophy']").click(function(e){
    //determine if control+click or mouse middle button
   if(e.ctrlKey==true || e.which==2){
        $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
         e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
        window.open($(this).attr("href"),'_blank');

   }
});
function foudertab(){
    $("#w").hide();
    $(".founders").show();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
    foudertab();
    $("#founders_tab").click(function(){
        $("#w").hide();
        $(".founders").show(300);
    });
    $(".nav-two a").click(function(e){


       // $(oldcontent).addClass('hidden');
      //});


      //$('#sidemenu a').removeClass('open');
      //$(this).addClass('open');

    foudertab();
    })
    $(".founders_img_area").click(function(){


     // var oldcontent = $('#sidemenu a.open').attr('href');
      var newcontent = $(this).attr('href');
      $(newcontent).trigger("click");

     // $(oldcontent).fadeOut('fast', function(){

       // $(newcontent).fadeIn().removeClass('hidden');
        $("#w").show(300);
        $(".founders").hide();
    }); 

});
```

[Live page](http://flutura.com/about_us_trial.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the name of each tab in the alt attribute of each anchor tag inside li like :

```
<li id="menu-item-301" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-301"><a href="about_us_trial.php">About Us</a>
                <div class="drop">
                  <ul class="sub-menu" id="about_drop">
                    <li id="menu-item-1722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1722"><a href="#company" alt="company_tab">Company</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1722"><a href="#founders" alt="founders_tab">The Founders</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1722"><a href="#team" alt="team_tab">Team</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1722"><a href="#accolades" alt="accolades_tab">Accolades</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1722"><a href="#careers" alt="careers_tab">Careers</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1722"><a href="#philosophy" alt="philosophy_tab">Philosophy</a></li>
                 </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
```

then in the js use  document.ready as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#about_drop li a').click(function(){
            $('#'+$(this).attr('alt')).click();
                    $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
            })
       });
```

Comment: but its working at my end.Have u put the name in the alt attributes correctly

Comment: @Dhanil  Here is the working fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/STeXX/embedded/result/

Comment: When we click on the dropdown(eg Team) the page is scrolling down, did you notice that? that is my problem.

Comment: it is opening the tab correctly. but now the page scrolling down. How to solve that?

Comment: @Dhanil try adding $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000); after .click() line. i have edited my answer for this as well. updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/STeXX/5/embedded/result/